# django file upload doesn't work: f.read() returns ''

Tags: django, json, upload

I'm trying to upload and parse json files using django. Everything works great up until the moment I need to parse the json. Then I get this error:

```
No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

Here's my code. (I'm following the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/), and overwriting the handle_uploaded_file method.)

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f, collection):
#  assert False, [f.name, f.size, f.read()[:50]]
  t = f.read()
  for j in serializers.deserialize("json", t):
    add_item_to_database(j)
```

The weird thing is that when I uncomment the "assert" line, I get this:

```
[u'myfile.json', 59478, '']
```

So it looks like my file is getting uploaded with the right size (I've verified this on the server), but the read command seems to be failing entirely.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's *type(f)* and *t* come out to? My suspicion is *.read()* works, but something isn't valid JSON.

Comment: From:   assert False, [f.name, f.size, f.read()[:50], type(f), type(t), len(t)]  I get, [u'wikileaks_comments.json', 59478, '', <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>, <type 'str'>,0]

Comment: Cool. And what's in the string?

Comment: Re: not valid JSON -- That was my first guess too. But the file was created using simplejson, and I've run it through a validator. I'm pretty confident the json isn't the problem.

Comment: Nothing -- it's a string of length zero.

Comment: It's supposed to be an array of simple objects, but I can't get django to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before. Your file has length, but reading it doesn't. I'm wondering if it's been read previously... try this:

```
f.seek(0)
f.read()
```